# Authorization issues after killing Xorg

Tags: permissions, mount, xorg, suspend

Because Xorg hang or because it used 4GB of memory because of some weird memory leak, I killed it and it restarted normally. I just needed to log in again through Slim, but after that until the next restart I experience several authorization issues, like:

- When trying to mount an USB thumb drive through Thunar or Nemo, by just clicking on the device in the location list, I get

  > Failed to mount "Transcend" Not authorized to perform operation.
- When trying to suspend, shut down, ..., e.g. with `xfce4-session-logout --suspend` it just will lock the screen instead of suspending, but `sudo pm-suspend` does work. That's why I guess that this is also an authorization problem.

Why does this happen? Could it be that I'm logged in twice, because killing Xorg didn't log me out correctly? Are there some locks somewhere? How can I make mounting and suspending work again like it would on a restart?

As per JdeBP's suggestion some additional information:
I'm using

- `Linux 4.5.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.5.1-1 (2016-04-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- mostly Debian sid with XFCE 4.12
- systemd as seen with `ps -p 1`
- `loginctl` shows:

  ```
  SESSION        UID USER   SEAT
       1       1000 mxm    seat0
  1 sessions listed.
  ```
- I do have polkitd running. `dpkg -l '*policy*'` shows `policykit-1 0.105-17`
- As for the kind of Desktop Bus, I tried `dpkg -l '*bus*'` (only those shown which seem important)

  ```
  ii  dbus                     1.10.12-1  amd64  simple interprocess messaging system (daemon and util
  ii  dbus-x11                 1.10.12-1  amd64  simple interprocess messaging system (X11 deps)
  ii  libdbus-1-3:amd64        1.10.12-1  amd64  simple interprocess messaging system (library)
  ii  libdbus-1-3:i386         1.10.12-1  i386   simple interprocess messaging system (library)
  ii  libdbus-glib-1-2:amd64   0.108-1    amd64  simple interprocess messaging system (GLib-based shar
  ii  libdbus-glib-1-dev       0.108-1    amd64  simple interprocess messaging system (GLib interface)
  ii  libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64  12.10.2-1  amd64  library for passing menus over DBus
  ii  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64 12.10.2-1  amd64  library for passing menus over DBus - GTK+ version
  ii  qdbus                    4:4.8.7+dfsg-9  amd64  Qt 4 D-Bus tool
  ```

`xfce4-session-logout --suspend` when it does not work, produces the following log lines:

- In `/var/log/{kern.log,syslog,messags}`

  > Dec 18 01:52:06 pc xfce4-notifyd[22273]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-awJrGEr9me: Connection refused

  Seems like this isn't the actual problem, just a problem with displaying notifications, but maybe it hints to another problem? `notify-send "test" "test"` works without problems, though.
- `/var/log/secure`, which I read is for PolicyKit, is empty.

After the mounting fail in Nemo I can't find any log message. I checked everything in `/var/log/` `dmesg` and also `~/.xsession-errors`.

First I tried `dbus-monitor` for the non-working `xfce4-session-logout --suspend` command. It gave not much, it showed `xfce4-session-logout` sending DBus messages to xfce-session manager which in turn, looking at the source code, sends a DBus message to systemd, which was not shown with `dbus-monitor`, so I tried it with the option `--system`, which seems to show communication with of systemd(?) with polkit:

```
method call time=1482033095.691432 sender=:1.1956 -> destination=org.freedesktop.login1 serial=19 path=/org/freedesktop/login1; interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager; member=Suspend
   boolean true
method call time=1482033095.691713 sender=:1.0 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=214 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.691733 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.0 serial=57 reply_serial=214
   uint32 1000
method call time=1482033095.691913 sender=:1.0 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=215 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.691929 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.0 serial=58 reply_serial=215
   uint32 1000
method call time=1482033095.692129 sender=:1.0 -> destination=org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 serial=216 path=/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority; interface=org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority; member=CheckAuthorization
   struct {
      string "system-bus-name"
      array [
         dict entry(
            string "name"
            variant                string ":1.1956"
         )
      ]
   }
   string "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend"
   array [
   ]
   uint32 1
   string ""
method call time=1482033095.692546 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=410 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.0"
method return time=1482033095.692564 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=272 reply_serial=410
   uint32 0
method call time=1482033095.692919 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=411 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.692936 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=273 reply_serial=411
   uint32 1000
method call time=1482033095.693205 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=412 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.693231 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=274 reply_serial=412
   uint32 1000
method call time=1482033095.693404 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=413 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.693420 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=275 reply_serial=413
   uint32 10534
method call time=1482033095.693977 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=414 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.693994 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=276 reply_serial=414
   uint32 10534
method call time=1482033095.694460 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=415 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.694478 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=277 reply_serial=415
   uint32 1000
method call time=1482033095.694663 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=416 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.694677 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=278 reply_serial=416
   uint32 10534
method call time=1482033095.695290 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=417 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.695307 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=279 reply_serial=417
   uint32 10534
method call time=1482033095.695791 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=418 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.695808 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=280 reply_serial=418
   uint32 1000
method call time=1482033095.696095 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=419 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.696112 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=281 reply_serial=419
   uint32 10534
method call time=1482033095.696641 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=420 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.696658 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=282 reply_serial=420
   uint32 10534
method call time=1482033095.697047 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=421 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.697063 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=283 reply_serial=421
   uint32 10534
method call time=1482033095.697365 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=422 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.697381 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=284 reply_serial=422
   uint32 10534
method return time=1482033095.697637 sender=:1.12 -> destination=:1.0 serial=423 reply_serial=216
   struct {
      boolean false
      boolean true
      array [
         dict entry(
            string "polkit.retains_authorization_after_challenge"
            string "1"
         )
      ]
   }
method call time=1482033095.697882 sender=:1.0 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=217 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.1956"
method return time=1482033095.697901 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.0 serial=59 reply_serial=217
   uint32 1000
error time=1482033095.697991 sender=:1.0 -> destination=:1.1956 error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InteractiveAuthorizationRequired reply_serial=19
   string "Interactive authentication required."
method call time=1482033097.707153 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=1 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=Hello
method return time=1482033097.707178 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.2260 serial=1 reply_serial=1
   string ":1.2260"
signal time=1482033097.707194 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=433 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.2260"
   string ""
   string ":1.2260"
signal time=1482033097.707212 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.2260 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.2260"
method call time=1482033097.707800 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=AddMatch
   string "type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged',path='/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority',arg0='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority'"
method return time=1482033097.707832 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.2260 serial=3 reply_serial=2
method call time=1482033097.707900 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=3 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=AddMatch
   string "type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1',interface='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority',path='/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority'"
method return time=1482033097.707920 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.2260 serial=4 reply_serial=3
method call time=1482033097.708001 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=4 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=AddMatch
   string "type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.DBus',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus',member='NameOwnerChanged',path='/org/freedesktop/DBus',arg0='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'"
method return time=1482033097.708020 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.2260 serial=5 reply_serial=4
method call time=1482033097.708137 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=5 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=StartServiceByName
   string "org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1"
   uint32 0
method return time=1482033097.708163 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.2260 serial=6 reply_serial=5
   uint32 2
method call time=1482033097.708484 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=6 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetNameOwner
   string "org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1"
method return time=1482033097.708504 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.2260 serial=7 reply_serial=6
   string ":1.12"
method call time=1482033097.708797 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=:1.12 serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
   string "org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority"
method return time=1482033097.709126 sender=:1.12 -> destination=:1.2260 serial=424 reply_serial=7
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "BackendName"
         variant             string "local"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "BackendVersion"
         variant             string "0.105"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "BackendFeatures"
         variant             uint32 1
      )
   ]
method call time=1482033097.709509 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=:1.12 serial=8 path=/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority; interface=org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority; member=EnumerateActions
   string ""
method return time=1482033097.712396 sender=:1.12 -> destination=:1.2260 serial=425 reply_serial=8
   array [
      [ ... 1800 lines of structs with policyKit actions ... ]
   ]
method call time=1482033097.720322 sender=:1.2260 -> destination=:1.12 serial=9 path=/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority; interface=org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority; member=CheckAuthorization
   struct {
      string "unix-process"
      array [
         dict entry(
            string "pid"
            variant                uint32 10534
         )
         dict entry(
            string "start-time"
            variant                uint64 71999741
         )
         dict entry(
            string "uid"
            variant                int32 1000
         )
      ]
   }
   string "org.xfce.session.xfsm-shutdown-helper"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "user"
         string "root (root)"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "command_line"
         string "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/session/xfsm-shutdown-helper --suspend"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "program"
         string "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/session/xfsm-shutdown-helper"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "polkit.gettext_domain"
         string "polkit-1"
      )
   ]
   uint32 1
   string ""
method call time=1482033097.720691 sender=:1.12 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=426 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetConnectionUnixUser
   string ":1.2260"
method return time=1482033097.720713 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.12 serial=285 reply_serial=426
   uint32 0
method return time=1482033097.720734 sender=:1.12 -> destination=:1.2260 serial=427 reply_serial=9
   struct {
      boolean false
      boolean true
      array [
      ]
   }
signal time=1482033097.720788 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.2260 serial=5 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.2260"
signal time=1482033097.720811 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=434 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.2260"
   string ":1.2260"
   string ""
```

Comment: You'll help answerers by telling (in the question) them such things as whether this is a systemd operating system, what `loginctl` says about your login session(s), whether you are using PolicyKit, and what its log, the system log, and the log of the Desktop Bus broker say is going on when you try these things.